# How to sync plist data to web server using AFNetworking3.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

i am using plist to save my data locally when network connection is not available, and when network is available i want to sync my locally saved data to the web server.

i am using this code. but i don't know whether the data is saved in server or not.

```
(IBAction)manualSync:(id)sender {

   NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
   AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

   NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example_url"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

   NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://plist_name"];
   NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:filePath progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
       if (error) {
           NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
       } else {
           NSLog(@"Success: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
       }
    }];
    [uploadTask resume];
}
```

i am assigning my api to the URL in which i want to save the data of plist, and my plist to the file path in which my data is already saved. can anyone solve this issue.

Comment: If there is no error then else {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
    } this code would get executed. Try puttin a brakpoint here or check the logs.

Comment: i am not getting any errors, but i am not getting response too

Comment: the breakpoint is directly jumping to [uploadTask resume]; without entering into the if condition

Comment: The breakpoint would be hit after some time when you get the response. In this case you can either completion handlers. Check this link for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728575/completion-block-after-web-service-finishes

Comment: but here i want to sync my plist data to the web server i.e api which is already existing within the project

Comment: my project getting crash and the reason is "[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter"

Comment: @CharishmaVasamsetti There you need to check in completion handler for getting server response, whether server process is able to save your file or not.

Comment: [NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: getting crash, may be location of file is not found therefore resulted variable path getting null. Here is my suggestion, to get location of file, you should know the name of bundle (Using NSBundle) and keep track of file where you saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use normal API Call to stored pList file to a server. **Becuase when you read plist file, your will data in NSDictionary and you send it server to store.**

To send plist values into server:

```
  AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSString *strWebService = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR_BASE_URL"];

NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YOUR_PLIST_NAME" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dicData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];



[manager POST:strWebService parameters:dicData constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData)
 {
 } progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress)
 {
 } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"%@",responseObject)
     ;
 } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
 }];
```

Comment: Can you send me your plist file? So I can check and let you know.

Comment: saving and retrieving of data is working but sync of data is not working

Comment: yes when i want sync my data its getting nil values

Comment: Call your API in postman and check wheather you will get error at there or not. If you get error in Postman, then issue is with your api code.

Comment: there is no error in the API its working properly i have checked it several times

Comment: Check the input value which you sending from your ios code and compare it with your postman request. It may case that you are sending some wrong data on server which it cannot handle it.

Comment: thank you very much for you immediate response, it was really very helpful, now the problem is solved, i can post the plist data to my web server. But here again i got small issue i.e, when i want to post a set of elements in the form array, its getting posted only 1 element of that array. But here i want to post all the elements at a time....what is the solution for this...?

Comment: @CharishmaVasamsetti happy to help you.

Comment: You can upvote and accept my answer, if it satisfied your question. About your new issue, do you have skype?

Comment: If you are sending any data in array then in api logic, we need to fetch as array. Otherwise server won't get proper data

Comment: i want to post strings in array one by one to the web server

Comment: You are correct at mobile side, but same way you send, server need to do coding to retrieve on same way

Comment: @CharishmaVasamsetti did you get solution?